# Call a user control function from parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user-control which is dynamically loaded to tab in page at runtime.

```
usrCtrl = (ControlName)LoadControl("Usercontrols/ControlName.ascx");
usrCtrl.ID = "Name";

tabpanel.Controls.Add(usrCtrl);
```

I have a function called `display()` in usercontrol. I want to call this usercontrol function from its parent page event.

Answer (score 0):

```
usrCtrl = (ControlName)LoadControl("Usercontrols/ControlName.ascx");
usrCtrl.ID = "Name";
//call your function here
usrCtrl.display();//this will call user control function

tabpanel.Controls.Add(usrCtrl);
```